# contagem de registros com Room e LiveData no android studio

Tags: android, android-room

Como eu chamo esta função no adaptador do viewmodel:

```
@Query("select * from PRODUTO")
int getCountProdutos();
```

Meu viewmodel:

```
public class ProdutoListViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

private final LiveData<List<PRODUTO>> itemAndPersonList;
private AppDatabase appDatabase;

  public ProdutoListViewModel(Application application) {
    super(application);
    this.Vid = Vid;
    appDatabase = AppDatabase.getDatabase(this.getApplication());
    itemAndPersonList = appDatabase.itemAndProdutoModel().getAllProdutoItems();
  }
```

Já tentei de varias maneiras:

```
    public long getCountProdutos(){
//        ProdutoModelDAO produtoModelDAO;
//        List<PRODUTO> dbproduto;
//        dbproduto = appDatabase.itemAndProdutoModel().getCountProdutos();

//        if(produtoModelDAO.getCountProdutos() != 0){
//            return produtoModelDAO.getCountProdutos();
//        }else{
//            return 0;
//        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qual erro você está recebendo ? bom me parece que você está tentando executar o código na `Main Thread`, coisa que a Google não recomenda.

Tente desse jeito:

```
    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            appDatabase.suaDao.getCountProdutos();
        }
    });
```